# Raspberry Pi error when connecting to Firebase

Tags: raspbian, python, networking

When I tried `from firebase import firebase` running in the Python 3 (IDLE) and Thonny Python IDE, it gives an error likes this at the first line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/nahh.py", line 1, in <module>
    from firebase import firebase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/thonny/backend.py", line 305, in _custom_import
    module = self._original_import(*args, **kw)
ImportError: No module named 'firebase'
```

I have tried many reinstalled Python to 3.5 or Firebase but does not work.

Comment: Do you have the firebase module actually installed (https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/)?

Answer (score 0):

**Question**

Python 3.5 FireBase import error

**Answer**

*Some newwibe tips*

Rpi Rasbian 2019apr version built in python 3.5.3 is OK.  Do not try to update python higher.  I once tried 3.6x and made a whole mess.  Of course old FireBase (and many other) packages often could not catch up new Raspbian/Python.  So I always try to be humble, check the change log and use one or two stable versions older than current/beta.  Also Check the FireBAse tutorials you are following to make sure if they are using old Jessie and python 2.7x.  You might need to fast backward to last decade. :)

Javascript FireBase import is a common newbie error.  The important thing to remember is to import only the app you want (/app), not the whole thing.  The following youTube might help. (The funny youtube guy David has a pretty cunning smile that is worth a thumbs up. :)

[How to import Firebase with JavaScript modules - Firebase 2018sep06](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGqKYpvLkhE)

Firebase python is even trickier than javascript/typescript.  I would recommend the following youTubes.

[Firebase Realtime Database using Python SDK - Rakibul Islam 2018feb17](https://rakibul.net/fb-realtime-db-python)

[Getting Started with Cloud Firestore with Python - thatJenPerson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yylnC3dr_no)

[image: python cloudstore]

Perhaps you might like to let us know which Raspbian version and FireBase SDK you are using, which tutorial/instruction guide your are following etc, then we can join in debugging.

***References***

[FireBase - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase)

> FireBase is a mobile and web application development platform
>   developed by FireBase in 2011, then acquired by Google in 2014.
>
> As of October 2018, the Firebase platform has 18 products, which are
>   used by 1.5 million apps.